# Share project's code between PC and Notebook

Tags: version-control, sharing

Sometimes I want to be able to work with my php code both from my PC and notebook. I know, that I can use git, but I don't want to make dirty commits just to transfer code from PC to notebook and back. So, may be you have experience with it, what tools I can use to share my project between PC and notebook, may be I should use `dropbox` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still recommend to use git (or some other SCM of your choice).

You can deal with dirty commits like this

- Create a feature branch for those commit
- When you produced a reasonable state, then

  - Merge feature branch to your main branch or
  - Squash all dirty commits to the one clean commit and merge(or rebase) it with your main branch

Comment: Thx for reply, it's quite strange, that I have not thought about it, maybe because I'm obsessed on how to do it without git. Your answer like a "bingo!" in my head. So, i will create a branch "transfer" for that purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use git or svn because of the commands You can use any of the cloud storage (onedrive, google drive, dropbox), these work well, I use all of them in some capacity and they are good. BUT youll always need internet in order to sync it accross. It will come down to preference and wheter any of these services are blocked by the firewall (in places like work etc if you want the code at work)

Comment: Thx for the reply. I heard from some friends, that they've had issues with source code, especially with .git folder, when they used same synchronization in cloud storage, so to use git is preferred, but I should have private repos, that I already have. Anyway, that solution takes place